# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'initMap' is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, undefined, runtime-error

visual studio pops up a notification saying "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'initMap' is undefined" and points to the line below that contains "initMap();".

Notice, i've included a reference to the javascript file i'm using in the aspx page.

### Error at: (this is from Default.aspx [dynamic] when debugging)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
initMap();Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
$create(Sys.UI._Timer, {"enabled":true,"interval":4000,"uniqueID":"Timer1"}, null, null, $get("Timer1"));
});
//]]>
<
```

### Default.aspx.cs:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("init"))
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
                    (this.GetType(), "init", "initMap();", true);
                //"<body onload="initialize()"> "
                //"initialize();"
            }
        }
    }
```

### Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="MyProject._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
    ......[some stuff here]
    </style>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&region=PK"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="defaultPage.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <form id="form1" name="form1" runat="server">
    ..... [some stuff here]
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### My defaultPage.js file contains the following:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(24.828417, 67.038445);
var browserSupportFlag = new Boolean();
var markersArray = [];
images = new Object();
images.length = 99;

function initMap() {
....[some code here]
}

....
[more functions here]
```

Comment: `initMap()` is undefined. May be it is defined in the page but it is defined *after* the line where you are calling the function. PS: you might want to remove the project name from the question.

Comment: currently I am calling the script in the .cs file at Page_Load in this way: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript                    (this.GetType(), "init", "initMap();", true);

Comment: thanks for the advice, i did what you said. I was torn between taking it off and keeping it. i didn't want to be too discreet and well, its not a terribly sensitive project. but anyway, its gone now :)

Comment: I am not sure how ASP.NET generates the HTML and JavaScript code. You can try loading the page in the browser as usual, then enter this in the console: `typeof initMap` (notice no round brackets). Check if it returns `function()` or `undefined`.

Comment: this is so weird... its all working now :s all i did was restart my pc and now it works... IE was misbehaving and being weird and still is, and i'm thinking of formatting my pc. i'm sorry if i wasted your time but i appreciate your input.

Comment: ok, well... not entirely true. it's breaking again when i click a button on the page that is supposed to redirect me to another page after adding some data to the query string

Comment: @Faizan: better test your code in FireFox with FireBug extension. The console inside FireBug will give you more details about what is going wrong. In IE8+ you can use debugging toolbar by pressing F12. The scripts tab might contain some hints.